# Javascript sort callback

Tags: javascript, sorting

I need to sort a big list of Javascript items and I'm using the `sort` function like this:

```
var sorted_list = non_sorted.sort(function(a,b){
// Sort stuff here
});
```

What I'd like to do is to call a function when the `sort` function is done.

Is it possible to add a callback function to sort or to trigger an event when when `sort` is over?

Comment: You can just add the function to call after you've sorted the list.

Comment: `.sort()` is synchronous.

Comment: As suggested, you can do `arr.sort(comparefn).arrMethod()` or `someFn(arr.sort(comparefn))` since *sort* returns the sorted object.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are overcomplicating it. The `sort` method isn't asynchronous, so you don't need a callback or an event. Just put your code after the code that calls `sort`:

```
var sorted_list = non_sorted.sort(function(a,b){
  // comparer
});
// The code just continues here after the sort
```

Answer (score 0):

The sort function is synchronous so you can simply do something right after the call but if you want another way:

```
Array.prototype.sortCallback = function(compareFunction, resultFunction){
    result = this.sort(compareFunction);
    resultFunction(result);
}
```

Usage:

```
non_sorted.sortCallback(function(a, b) {
  // Sort stuff here
}, function(sorted) {
   // Do something with the sorted array
});
```

Comment: @epascarello just for the hell of it :P And I figured I'd make it a prototype just to show how this can be done.

Comment: Consider replacing `resultFunction(result)` with `resultFunction.apply(result, arguments)` to allow arguments to be passed to *resultFunction*. But extending built–ins isn't a good idea.

Answer (score -5):

this is a little dirty but it works:

slow enough for the sort function (within reason) and faster than the naked eye.

```
function sort_with_callback() {

            run_sort_function();

            setTimeout(function() { run_callback()},  3);}
```